# I want to retrieve data from SQL lite as an array of object using android

Tags: android

```
 public List<Report> selectAll() {
    List<Report> list = new ArrayList<Report>();
    Report report = new Report();
    int id,Temp;
    String Date,Tank,Tankuse;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "select ID, Date,Temp,Tank,Tankuse from "+TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

       id=cursor.getInt(0);
       report.setID(id);
        Date=cursor.getString(1);
        report.setDateTime(Date);
        Temp=cursor.getInt(2);
        report.setTemp(Temp);
        Tank=cursor.getString(3);
        report.setTank(Tank);
        Tankuse=cursor.getString(4);
        report.setTank(Tankuse);
        list.add(report);
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}
```

how i can retrieve the data as array of objects this is my first time Using SQL lite i use 3 tires architecture in asp.net but i don't know how that's work here so can some tell me how or what i should change in my code to make it return an array of object ?

Comment: Your approach should be okay, are you having any issues? All you need is a for loop. I can answer that if you want.

Comment: check this tutorial for more info http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I hope if you can give me any example @DanielK

Comment: @AbdalrahmanMakahleh, I was beat to it :)

Comment: @DanielK Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example:**

```
 public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
        // Adding contact to list
        contactList.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
return contactList;
}
```